# How to use anchor with offset for icon?

Tags: openlayers

I use the following icon:

```
  this.image = new Icon({
      anchor: [0.5, 1],
      anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
      anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
      src: `${this.baseUrl}assets/images/a.png`,
    });
```

This code sets positon to y=height of image. How to set offset for `anchor: [0.5, 1]`?

I need to get `anchor: [0.5, 1 - offset]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To shift image from position specified by `anchor` option, you can use icon `displacement` option (see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_Icon-Icon.html):

```
this.image = new Icon({
  anchor: [0.5, 1],
  anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
  anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
  displacement: [0, -offset],
  src: `${this.baseUrl}assets/images/a.png`,
});
```